# Trying to add a link to edit and show pages from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm trying to add edit and show links on an index page in rails but I'm getting an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SuppsController#edit
Couldn't find Supp with 'id'=#Supp::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd2f31f9370>
```

**Action:**

```
def edit
  @supp = Supp.find(params[:id])
end
```

**My index loop is:**

```
<% @supp.each do |user| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.bio %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_supp_path(@supp) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "show", supp_path(@supp) %></td>
</tr>
```

**Controller:**

```
def edit
    @supp = Supp.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want to achieve the following:

```
<% @supp.each do |user| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= user.id %></td>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.bio %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_supp_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "show", supp_path(user) %></td>
</tr>
```

Note that I changed the edit and show links to link to the specific user, rather than your entire `Supp`'s.

Let me know if this worked :)

Comment: @stoob If this is the answer mark it as solution please.

Comment: Nice to see it helped :) happy, rails coding ;)